# How to show or hide text in Microsoft Word on button press

Tags: microsoft-word, iframe

I have a very long word document which consists primarily of two sections.

- Code
- Not Code (ignore the fact that any document with code has only these two sections)

The code samples are often very long but I am unable to shorten them.

Is there a way to show/hide a section of the text when a button is pressed or an alternative where I can place a couple of pages of text in an "iframe" type style such as:

```
<iframe src="http://www.wikipedia.org" width="1000" height="200"></iframe>
```

Except instead of "Wikipedia" it shows a highlighted extract that.

I've read the information [here](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB564GB564&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hide%20text%20in%20word%202010) but it would be nice if there was an alternative that let the user create a spoiler-type thing.

Note - I hope this is on-topic, I've read the page on superuser and it appears to be.  Any notes of improvements that I could make would be largely helpful.

Comment: I have sorted this by placing all code at the end of the file, and hyper linked to it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can post an answer to your own question and after 2 days, accept it as the answer.  This will benefit others who have your same question.  Thanks for your contrition!